# Meaning of $f_n\vert{_K} \to f\vert{_K}$

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

On this definition of compact convergence : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence.

I dont understand how to read it, I dont know what the vertical bar means.

Thanks.

Comment: It's function restriction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)). That is, $f|_K$ has the same rule as $f$ but has the reduced domain $K$.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn Thanks.